# Non-exhaustive patterns in a function [Haskell]

Tags: haskell

I have to make a function neighbours :: [((String, String), Int)] -> String -> [(String, Int)]

This is the function I came up with:

```
neighbours pairs@((x1,x2):xs) inputWord
 | pairs == [] = []
 | fst x1 == inputWord = ((snd x1), x2) : (neighbours xs inputWord)
 | snd x1 == inputWord = ((fst x1), x2) : (neighbours xs inputWord)
 | otherwise = (neighbours xs inputWord)
```

The output is supposed to be a list of tuples with the strings that were paired with inputWord in the tuple x1, together with the integer x2

The problem is that I get non-exhaustive patterns that I don't believe should be there.

I tried to replace `pairs == [] = []` with `xs == [] = []`

This made the non-exhaustive patterns disappear for when the list was not empty, but it also prevented the function from traversing the last tuple of tuples.

Comment: Since you usee as pattern `pairs@((x1,x2):xs)`, `pairs == []` can never be true.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean

Comment: do you understand what the `(_:_)` pattern means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only pattern you specify is:

```
neighbours pairs@((x1,x2):xs) inputWord
```

This thus means that this only works for non-empty lists. Indeed, the pattern `((x1, x2):xs)` "fires" given it matches with a "cons" with `(x1, x2)` the first element of the list, and `xs` the rest of the elements.

The check `pair == []` will never succeed, since the pattern already means that this can never be an empty list.

We can add a clause for the empty list pattern, for example as first pattern to match. Furthermore we can improve the readability of the code by using the `(((x11, x12), x2):xs)` pattern for a non-empty list. We then do not need to use `fst` and `snd`, but can use `x11` and `x12` directly:

```
neighbours :: Eq a => [((a, a), b)] -> a -> [(a, b)]
neighbours [] _ = []
neighbours pairs@(((x11, x12),x2):xs) inputWord
    | inputWord == x11 = (x11, x2) : tl
    | inputWord == x12 = (x12, x2) : tl
    | otherwise = tl
    where tl = neighbours xs inputWord
```

For example:

```
Prelude> neighbours [(('a', 'b'), 1), (('b', 'a'), 2), (('b', 'b'), 3), (('a', 'a'), 4)] 'a'
[('a',1),('a',2),('a',4)]
```

This function is however a bit "asymetrical" since for the two elements in the tuple, it "prefers" the first element over the second element. If the two items `x11` and `x12` are both equal to `inputWord`, it might make more sense to *yield* them both.

Answer (score 1):

If you define a helper function to do the comparison to `inputWord`, the definition of `neighbors` becomes much simpler:

```
-- You can use other, more descriptive names instead.
type Foo = ((String, String), Int)
type Bar = (String, Int)

-- If it seems odd that I'm using [Bar] instead of Maybe Bar, see below
myLookup :: String -> Foo -> [Bar]
myLookup s ((s1, s2), i) | s == s1 = [(s2, i)]
                         | s == s2 = [(s1, i)]
                         | otherwise = []

neighbors :: [Foo] -> String -> [Bar]
neighbors [] _ = []
neighbors (x:xs) inputWord = case myLookup inputWord x of
                               []  ->     neighbors xs inputWord
                               [y] -> y : neighbors xs inputWord
```

It can be further simplified using `concatMap`, which simply concatenates
the results of applying `myLookup inputWord` to each element of the input.

```
neighbors :: [Foo] -> String -> [Bar]
neighbors xs inputWord = concatMap (myLookup inputWord) xs
```

---

With this pattern in mind, we can switch to using the stricter `Maybe Bar` return type for `myLookup` by using `mapMaybe` from `Data.Maybe` instead of `concatMap`.

```
import Data.Maybe (mapMaybe)

type Foo = ((String, String), Int)
type Bar = (String, Int)

myLookup :: String -> Foo -> Maybe Bar
myLookup s ((s1, s2), i) | s == s1 = Just (s2, i)
                         | s == s2 = Just (s1, i)
                         | otherwise = Nothing

neighbors :: [Foo] -> String -> [Bar]
neighbors xs inputWord = mapMaybe (myLookup inputWord) xs
```